# Android SDK source page : OEM Drivers Huawei link is broken

Tags: usb, libusb

In the Android source download links for OEM USB Drivers at http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html  - the link for the Huawei driver results in a page not found,  anyone have an updated working link for the Huawei USB Driver? Trying to test Android 2.2 app on an Huawei M835 (aka IDEOS)  Any help would be appreciated!   BThe current link shown there = http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/downloadCenter.do?method=list&flay=software&directoryId=20&treeId=0

Answer (score 1):

Actually my Huawei will automatically mount SD card and autorun tool that will install driver.

Else try this link:
[Huawei Android 2.2 USB Driver](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/downloadCenter.do?method=toDownloadFile&flay=software&softid=NDA0NTA=)

Comment: It seems huaweidevice.com is broken.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

This one is working currently, you can also go to their homepage->download in the footer bar->search "usb"
http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/downloadCenter.do?method=toDownloadFile&flay=software&softid=Mzk1MzA=

Comment: The link is broken